# HTML/CSS How do I get 2 completely independant scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

So I've coded something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ck393z8/
(It's a simplified version of a design that I'm preparing for a website)

HTML:

```
<table class="questionsTable">
    <col width="100" />
    <tr>
        <td class="questionsList" rowspan="1">
            <div id="scroll">
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td height="auto">
            <div id="image"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#thingy {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

#image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.questionsTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The left side is a menu with various buttons that modify the content on the right, but here's the problem:
Not all buttons on the left can be reached when the image is big, which is the case now. In those moments I need to scroll the right scroll bar down, otherwise not all elements on the left can be reached. I would obviously want both areas to be independent from one another, you  only scroll on the right to control the image, and you only scroll on the left to control the menu.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<body>
    <!-- Main container to hold all sections and each section will have their own scrollbars -->
    <div>
        <!-- Left section with same height -->
        <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto;float:left; width:45%;">
            <div id="scroll">
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
                <div id="thingy"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Right section with same height -->
        <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto;float:right; width:45%">
            <div id="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```